# docker-compose does not start the specified stage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

I am trying to create a multi stage Dockerfile, where the first stage is meant to be started in development environment (simple dev server) and the second stage is meant for production (full size web server).

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14 as develop
...
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000


FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14 as production
...
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 backend.wsgi
```

I am trying to specify the target stage in docker-compose.yml like so:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      target: develop
      ...
```

But it does not have any effect. Even when I set the target to `OohEehOohAhAahTingTangWallaWallaBingBang`, there is no error and the production server (last stage in Dockerfile) starts.

So, how to specify which target should be started in docker-compose.yml ?

EDIT: I am using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with Ubuntu-20.04

```
$ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.0.0-rc.1
```

Comment: this is not the recommended way to separate dev and prod images though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the behaviour of docker-compose is buggy. It DOES respect the `target` but only when building - when running `docker-compose up`, it just starts the image that was built last.

So if I set `target: develop`, then `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` (or `... up --build`), then it will start the target `develop` (simple dev server).

If I then set `target: production`, then `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` (or `... up --build`), then it will start the target `production` (full size server).

If I then set `target: develop` again, then `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` (or `... up --build`), then it will start the target `develop` (simple dev server).

Also, it only complains that the target does not exist when building images, not starting containers:

```
failed to create LLB definition: target stage OohEehOohAhAahTingTangWallaWallaBingBang could not be found
```

Answer (score -1):

The `target` keywork is supported since **docker compose** file format `3.4` as stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#target).

The `3.4` file format is implemented since **docker compose** version `1.17.0` as stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1170).

Which **docker compose** release are you using?

**Edit**

I suggest you to install manually the last official release as describe [in the official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose) by:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**NB:**: first of all remove the one installed by `apt`.

Comment: I have v2.0.0-rc.1

Comment: How is it possibile? The latest available is the 1.29.2 as per https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/ .

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using WSL, could that be the reason?

Comment: It does not matter. The question is the same: how can you use a version not yet release? Try to manually downoad docker compose of the right version and try with it.

Comment: Are you implying that I am lying? Or the --version output is lying to me? I just followed the https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/ which is the right solution... is there's any righter?

Comment: I am referring to the version you got from the command line. I edit my post with another suggestion.